# How to stop infinite loop in swift during action? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn how to use "ON" and "OFF" buttons and the basics of swift in general. Everything is going well but when I try to create an infinite loop of vibration using the "ON" UIButton, the loop keeps reiterating and I can't press the "OFF" button to stop it.

I tried looking up ways to stop it but none of them mention how to apply the code. I am still new and learning how to use swift. I read about "UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction" but I don't know how to put it into my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func onSwitch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = "ON"
    vibrate()
}


@IBAction func offSwitch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = "OFF"
    vibrate()
}


func vibrate() {
    while label.text == "ON" {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but is this a threading issue?

Comment: 1. Don't use C style to code in Swift and 2. in the method vibrate, dispatch the work to a background thread with a little sleep between calls. You can also recursively call the method with a sleep.

Comment: Dispatching to a background thread worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is continuously re-running tasks in while loop. This is happening on a main thread, so your application is unable to catch off button tap, because every tick is consumed to re-run the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound().

Comment: Even though you provide the explanation for the problem in the question, you don't actually provide a solution to the problem. I'd suggest including an alternative, working solution to the one in the question to improve the quality of your answer even further and provide more help to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The While Loop is wrong choice here !
You only vibrate is once by replacing the While With if condition to test your code correctly

OR

you can use Timer to vibrate every 3-5 Seconds

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.vibrate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// must be internal or public. 
@objc func vibrate() {
    // Something cool
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. For now I managed to make it work by dispatching it to a background thread and adding a small interval using usleep(). I will give this a try in the future